# plotting annotation in scatter chart

Tags: matplotlib, annotations, scatter, obspy, pythonplotter

Plotting scatters I am using this code
[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8cZT.png)

But I need to appear the only date annotation ( not houres:minutes:seconds) as I show
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nLTzO.jpg)

Comment: Please [add](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71454709/edit) your code together with test data as text, never as image.  If you put your code between triple backticks and add a Python tag, (so ```python,  on a separate line) the code will be colored automatically.

Comment: Note that to get the first 10 characters of `str(x)`, you can use `str(x)[:10]`.